# Prevent empty inputs from passing empty strings javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So, if I have a form like this

```html
<form action='/admin' method='post'>
  <input class='form-control' name='truckNumber' type='number'></input>
  <input class='form-control' name='truckNumber' type='number'></input>
  <input class='form-control' name='truckNumber' type='number'></input>
  <input class='form-control' name='truckNumber' type='number'></input>
  <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'></input>
</form>
```

If the user doesn't fill out any of the fields, I get an array posted with values ['','','','']. Is there a way to prevent the values from being posted if the input is left blank?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `required` attribute of html within each input element.
If you want to do it with JavaScript then simply traverse array and check if any value is empty.

Comment: Not trying to require the field, trying to prevent empty strings from being posted.

Comment: Then try to get all fields from form and manually . before sending data to ajax

Comment: If you want to validate data on frontend then don't use form before it will call backend api , you need to add seperate input and then validate each and every field on frontend before data to server.

Answer (score 0):

On submit, check for empty inputs and give them the `disabled` attribute. Disabled inputs will not be submitted.

Example:

```js
document.querySelector('.btn-primary').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');
  inputs.forEach(function(item, i) {
    if (item.value.length == 0) item.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
  // document.querySelector("form").submit();
});
```

```css
input:disabled {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form action='/admin' method='post'>
  <input class='form-control' name='truckNumber' type='number'>
  <input class='form-control' name='truckNumber' type='number'>
  <input class='form-control' name='truckNumber' type='number'>
  <input class='form-control' name='truckNumber' type='number'>
  <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [required](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) like this:

```
<form action='/admin' method='post'>
  <input class='form-control' name='truckNumber' type='number' required></input>
  <input class='form-control' name='truckNumber' type='number' required></input>
  <input class='form-control' name='truckNumber' type='number' required></input>
  <input class='form-control' name='truckNumber' type='number' required></input>
  <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'></input>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't want the field to be required. Not all of the fields need to have values.